# Multiple consumer in kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have one kakfa topic which have 10 partitions and i have 2 consumers with same Group like below
**Consumer 1**

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic2", groupId = "group_id",containerFactory="jsonKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consume(Person person) {}
```

**Consumer2**

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic2", groupId = "group_id",containerFactory="jsonKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consume(Person person) {}
```

If i want to increase the consumers say 10 then do i need to create replica of my method (consume) to create more consumers or do we have any alternative options too.

Comment: Use `concurrency=10` ?

Comment: concurrency is one option but this will apply to all the json object who is using containerFactory="jsonKafkaListenerContainerFactory" common to all objects